# Would it be idiomatic to use 'then' where I have in this sentence?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: Do you think he's in heaven?

B: Yes.

A: **Then** he's together with Grandma.

Would it be completely idiomatic to use **then** where I have in the sentence? (to mean *in that case; therefore.*)

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly idiomatic (at least in my dialect of northeastern US English).

Comment: If he's in hell, then he's together with Grandpa?